# How do I properly use PHP to encode MySQL object into JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I am trying to iterate through a MySQL object and use an ajax call on another page to append the data but I can't get the php to return valid JSON to the callback.

This one obviously doesn't work...

```
<?php

    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "blah";
    $db_pass = "blah";
    $db_name = "chat";
    $mysqli = new MySQLi($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $mysqli->query($myQuery) or die($mysqli->error);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo json_encode($row);

?>
```

Or this one...

```
<?php

    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "blah";
    $db_pass = "blah";
    $db_name = "chat";
    $mysqli = new MySQLi($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $mysqli->query($myQuery) or die($mysqli->error);
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
        echo json_encode($row) . ", ";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$data = array();

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $data[] = json_encode($row);
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

This should do it. Also, you can use http://jsonlint.com/ to see what are the problems with your JSON output.

**Update:** using `fetch_all()` might be a good idea too

```
$data = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: +1 Or maybe use `fetch_all()`. Note: I guess you don't need  `. ", "`.

Comment: @tereško yeah! this is a good one, but now I don't know what to do with the callback... before I was using `$("#diver").append("<p>" + data.id + "</p>");` but I just get an `undefined` variable.

Comment: @nipponese , try doing `console.dir(data);` in the callback (that's assuming that you have already parsed the JSON on JS side). Maybe the names of parameters have changed. Also, you are returning an array of objects instead of just a single object , that has been encode as JSON string. It would be something like `data[0].id` now.

Comment: Oh, yeah, duh, it's an array now. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey! Check that you don't encode twice! It will add back slashesin your json data.

I think it should look like:



    $data[] = $row; NOT $data[] = json_encode($row);

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
    $json = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $json[]=$row;
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

and I get something like this

[
{"id":"2","usuario":"zeldafranco","password":"lol"},{"id":"3","usuario":"franco","password":"franco"},{"id":"4","usuario":"peteko","password":"sanpeteko"},{"id":"5","usuario":"prueba","password":"prueba"},{"id":"6","usuario":"test","password":"test"},
{"id":"7","usuario":"pibe","password":"hola"},
{"id":"8","usuario":"que ase","password":"que ase"},{"id":"9","usuario":"trt","password":"trt"},
{"id":"10","usuario":"tyt","password":"tyt"}
]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and its Valid JSON according to JSONLint.

Answer (score -2):

```
$arrUsers = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {



 $arrUsers['id'] = $row['name'];
    $arrUsers['col1'] = $row['col1'];
    $arrUsers['col2'] = $row['col2'];

    array_push($arrUsers,$row_array);

}

echo json_encode($arrUsers);
```